# jQuery Full Calendar - Event time is not binded correctly on page load

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, fullcalendar, asp.net-ajax

**Issue:** On document.ready, full calender binds all the event details including the start & end date, but not time i.e the event is rendered in appropriate date slot as expected, **but not in appropriate time slot**.

**Default.aspx:** Rendering the full calendar.

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    eventClick: updateEvent,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: selectDate,
    editable: true,
    events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
    eventDrop: eventDropped,
    eventResize: eventResized,
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
    //alert(event.title);
        element.qtip({
            content: {
                text: qTipText(event.start, event.end, event.description),
                title: '<strong>' + event.title + '</strong>'
            },
            position: {
                my: 'bottom left',
                at: 'top right'
            },
            style: { classes: 'qtip-shadow qtip-rounded' }
        });
    }
    });
```

Note: Plese find the attached shapshots for the database, default.aspx & JsonResponse.ashx json result.

[image: Default.aspx]

[image: JsonResponse]

[image: database]

In Default.aspx Event1 has start & end time - 12:00:00 AM TO 1:00:00 AM in the database, but it renders under 06:30:00 - 07:00:00 slot which is incorrect.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your code i found that the problem was that you where changing the time you where saving to the database with settings the .ToUniversalTime()
So when you select 7AM in the calendar it would save 11AM to the database.

```
        start = Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.start).ToUniversalTime(),
        end = Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.end).ToUniversalTime(),
```

If you just remove the .ToUniversalTime() at the start and end date it wil save the correct date and time to the database and then ofcourse also load the correct date and time after refresh.

```
        start = Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.start),
        end = Convert.ToDateTime(improperEvent.end),
```

Answer (score 1):

`Event1` start is `Date(1457893800000)` which equals Sun, 13 Mar 2016 18:30:00 GMT.

Thus, this is probably a time zone issue: your calendar is displaying the events in GMT, whereas you need it to be in local time.

My suggestion is to keep the time values in the database as they are, i.e., in UTC time, and handle the translation to local time in the browser.

See [timezone](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/) in FullCalendar documentation for further advice.

Comment: GMT and UTC share the same current time. see the difference [here](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html). You only need to tell `FullCalendar` to use local time. To start with, just add `timezone: 'local'` to your `FullCalendar` options.